# How to decrease wifi link quality and/or wifi signal level?

Tags: raspberry-pi, wifi

I have been following a tutorial that enables you to play around with the TXPOWER parameter of your wifi card / wifi adapter:

http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/set-your-wi-fi-cards-tx-power-higher-than-30-dbm-0149606/

You can easily boost up your wifi range when increasing the TXPOWER. 
Now, most people want to improve their wifi signal strength of their home router, right. But in my case, I would like my  home router (which runs on a raspberry pi) to have a relative small wifi signal radius (say, a radius of 2 meters), so that you actually need to physically look for the pi home router when trying to connect to it.

I have learned that this tutorial does not do a thing with the wifi link quality and/or the wifi signal level and thus does not influence the wifi radius of my pi home router.

[link quality & signal level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aeNG.png)

Do you guys have any ideas/thoughts about how to decrease link quality and/or wifi signal level (e.g Link Quality = 12/70 and Signal level =-10dBm) ? Is this even possible ?

I am using a Tp-Link TL-WN722N IEEE 802.11n USB - Wi-Fi Adapter. 
WIRELESS LITE N ADAPTER 150M USB HIGH GAIN 1DETACHABLE ANTENNA WL-AP. 
150 Mbps - External

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend reviewing this section from your link:

> QUICK DECIBEL UNDERSTANDING:
>
> Every 10 decibels is a 10X increase in power starting from 1 dBm equal
>   to 1mW... 10 dBm equals 10 mW, 20 dBm equals 100 mW, 30 dBm equals
>   1000 mW, and so on. Every 3 decibels is approximately double that of
>   the prior power, so 30 dBm is 1000 mW, if we add 3 dBm, then we can
>   double the power such that 33 dBm is about equal to 2000 mW.

It appears to me that you are able to modify the transmit power of your adapter as the tutorial states. Are you saying this is not working? If you set your transmit power to something extremely low (-30dBm, for example) you would effectively be turning off the transmitter. Keep increasing that value until you get your desired coverage radius.

If the transmit power parameter is not functioning as per the tutorial, then there are other means to achieve reduced coverage. The model you specified has a detachable antenna....so detach it. This would definitely reduce your coverage. However, if it reduces coverage too much, you could simply add an inline attenuator. Fortunately, your antenna uses an SMA connector which is very common. You can find many SMA attenuators on [ebay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=sma%20attenuator%20kit&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xsma%20attenuator.TRS0&_nkw=sma%20attenuator&_sacat=0) with different attenuation values. Experiment with different values until you get the desired coverage.

And if *that* doesn't work, just wrap a bunch of aluminum foil around the thing lol.